# Include Bootstrap in web pack starter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, angular2-template, webpack-style-loader

I am very new to Angular2. I am geeting so many issues to include bootstrap3 with less support in angular2 webpack starter(https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

I want to include bootstrap in aboove starter application following this link steps
(https://github.com/ghillert/angular2-webpack-starter-bootstrap)

and there in No **vendor.ts** file, In all searches they are using vendor.ts

I am unable to do this , I am getting so many errors

1)**BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'style-loader' instead of 'style'.**

2)**getting `request of a dependency is an expression` warning**

Please any one can explain me to do all steps for present web pack stater

Thank you

Comment: Even I have similar issue